# "Permission to path denied" in Xamarin when trying to save file to user device, no matter what

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

When I try to do a "File.WriteBytes" or something similar (to save a byte file to user device) an error of permission to access the path always blows up. I tried everything, permissions on Manifest, using the plugin Permissions, changing the path to save it...funny how with Download Manager I can download a file in the same folder without errors. Any idea what's happening?

```
private async void OnDownloadStart(object sender, Android.Webkit.DownloadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var url = e.Url;
            var url_formatted = url.Split(",");
            var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(url_formatted[1]);
            var decoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
            var directory = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath;

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(directory,
                      FileMode.Create,
                      FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                      FileShare.ReadWrite,
                      4096,
                      FileOptions.Asynchronous);

            fs.Write(base64EncodedBytes, 0, base64EncodedBytes.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: perhaps if you shared the relevant code and exact path(s) you are trying to use we could help you.  If you are trying to write to the public Downloads folder on newer versions of Android, then you should use `DownloadManager` that is a system service designed specifically to write to that folder.

Comment: I updated with some code. Noting that I'm trying to save a base 64 decoded string, which I think I can't do with DownloadManager. Now I'm trying with FileStream .Write, with the same permission denied exception blowing up.

Comment: You can check the answer in the thread "[Access to the path is denied xamarin forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/454560/access-to-the-path-is-denied-xamarin-forms)" to see if it helps you.